# How to use difirent type of data in a single collection in java

Tags: java, android

I want to make this type format of data using collection.

```
[username] = test
[password] = test
[model] = City
[action] = add
[City] = Array
    (
        [name] = Added from me
        [state_id] = 1243
    )
```

Comment: are all of your values strings ?

Comment: This is technically doable in Java, but that doesn't mean you _should_ do it.  It's _much_ better to write your own classes to handle the appropriate types for each of the fields.  Mixing types together like this leads to smelly, unmaintainable code.

Comment: Why don't you create a class containing those items and store each object of that class in a collection (list or map if you need to query easily by username for example)?

Answer (score 9):

`Map` is good fit here

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
map.put("username", "test@test.com");
map.put("city", arrayOfCity);
```

Make sure if you are using `HashMap` implementation then you need to provide sensible version of `hashcode()` and `equals()` for your custom type you add to `Map`

*If you have fixed set of property then you should go with class and create one, if not then use map*

Comment: it accepts only NameValuePair then we can do this UrlEncodedFormEntity(map)

Comment: If you have fixed set of property then you can go with class and create one, if not then use map

Answer (score 7):

I would collect your objects into a single object:

```
public class Person {

     private final String username;
     private final String[] cities;


     public Person(String username, String[] cities){
          this.username = username;
          this.cities = cities;
     }

     public String getUsername(){
          return this.username;
     }

     public String[] getCities(){  // or pass an int and return one city
          return this.cities; 
     }
}
```

You could then have it in one collection:

```
Person p1 = new Person("test@test.com", new String[]{"Liverpool","London"});
Person p2 = new Person("another@test.com", new String[]{"New York","California"});

List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
people.add(p1);
people.add(p2);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use Java HashMap. This will provide you what exactly you need.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a **pojo** mapping to the fields mentioned by you. This will be **clearer** than using a collection to store individual entities.